# How to select and merge vertices into separate triangles?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

For my blender model, I have an image of a half-sphere. On its face it is triangulated and I want to merge the triangles together so they are like the portion that the red arrow is pointing to:

[image]

What I have tried doing is first going to select on the bottom left, and then using circle select. I selected the areas and I tried doing many different things:

First, I tried pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> and I was given the choice of merging at center, at cursor, or collapse. None of these can give the function I need.

Then, I tried pressing *Select > Vertices > Connect* and nothing happened.

I have tried using this: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Vertices/

Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: Try selecting everything and pressing Alt+J

Answer (score 1):

2. Switch to edge select mode (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>*> Edge*)
3. Select the edges you want to cut. Border select works well (<kbd>B</kbd>), or you can select a couple edges like the ones you want to select and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>*> Face Angles*.
4. Press <kbd>W</kbd>*> Subdivide* and turn up the smoothness in the redo panel.

   [image]

## Note

I very much recommend working with quads instead, and using a [triangulate modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Triangulate) to non-destructively triangulate the mesh in realtime.

Answer (score 1):

By my count, the part of the sphere in which you have consolidated the triangles into quads amounts to 1/8 of the sphere. I would delete the other 7/8 of the sphere, and use an array modifier to add 7 more instances, and then apply the modifier to achieve what you are wanting to do.